# onActivityResult not called in fragment android

Tags: android, fragment

This is my code to take picture from gallery.

```
public class FragmentLayout1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    View root;
    Context c;
    Button add_image;
    DialogAddImage image;
    RelativeLayout layout_image;
    String path;
    RunAnimations anima;


    public void setContext(Context c){
        this.c = c;
        Constants con = new Constants(c);   
    }

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        anima = new RunAnimations();
        image = new DialogAddImage((Activity) c);

        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        path = bun.getString("path");

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1, container, false);
        add_image = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        add_image.setOnClickListener(this);

        layout_image = (RelativeLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.layout_image);

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)){
            Log.e("path", path);
             Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
             layout_image.setBackground(d);
        }


        return root;


    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        anima.loadAnimationView(c, R.anim.alpha_button, v);
        if(v == add_image){
            image.showDialog();
        }

    }


     //============= fungsi untuk menerima hasil pilihan user dalam kotak dialog ambil gambar=============
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("result", "Result");
        new ImageResult((Activity) c).resultOfImage(requestCode, resultCode, data, image.getUri(), false);
    }
```

in method on click , I've button add_image. add_image will show a dialog for user to take picture from camera or gallery
And this is my dialog code

```
public class DialogAddImage{
    private Activity c;
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private Dialog dialog;
    AnimasiActivity aa;
    Button camera, galeri;

    public DialogAddImage(Activity c){
        this.c = c;

        aa = new AnimasiActivity(c);
        setDialog();
    }

    //untuk mendapatkan uri yang menyimpan informasi path file image
    public Uri getUri(){
        return mImageCaptureUri;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setDialog(){       
        dialog = new Dialog(c);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_image);           
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

        camera = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        galeri = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        //kalo user pilih dari kamera
        camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                hideDialog();
                Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                String file_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                File file = new File(Constants.path_image +file_name + ".jpg");
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                try {                        
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    intent.putExtra("mImageCaptureUri", mImageCaptureUri);                            

                    aa.startForwardForResult(intent, Constants.PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();   
                }  



            }
        });

        //kalo user pilih dari galery
        galeri.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {                
                hideDialog();
                Intent intent = new Intent(); 
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);                   

                aa.startForwardForResult(intent, Constants.PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }

        });



    }

    public void showDialog(){

        dialog.show();
    }

    public void hideDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

But when I've choose image from gallery , this image not showing in my fragment. And method onActivityResult never called, but why??? any solution , please

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: Duplicate question [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29369154/1283715)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override `onActivityResult` in parent Activity i.e. parent of all fragment

Comment: have same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059269/why-the-facebook-sharing-is-not-working-with-fragments

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you call startActivityForResult() and not getActivity().startActivityForResult() from your fragment. refer [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment#answer-11011686)

Answer (score 4):

If you are overriding `onActivityResult` in your `Activity` then make sure you do call `super.onActivityResult` there too in order to propagate the result to your fragments.

Comment: can you tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059269/why-the-facebook-sharing-is-not-working-with-fragments

Comment: Saved my day! There are so many code snippets out there overriding onActivityResult without calling super. I thought it does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Also if you call `startActivityForResult()` from your fragment, then `onActivityResult()` will be called in your fragment. And if you call `startActivityForResult()` from your activity, then `onActivityResult()` will be called in your activity. Basically where you call `startActivityForResult()` is where `onActivityResult()` will be called.

Another thing, in Android the prefered way to create dialogs is to extend the [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is very sensitive and little tricky the observation(fix) i have made for this as follows,

When u called Activity B from Activity A the source activity(A) instance should be in stack(memory) to invoke "onActivityResult" callback.

The issue explained with reason below,

**Observation**: From Material design back and NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask - the description of navigateUpFromSameTask as follows
"Convenience method that is equivalent to calling navigateUpTo(sourceActivity, getParentActivityIntent (sourceActivity)). sourceActivity will be finished by this call"

**remember sourceActivity (A) is removed from stack(memory) when used this method.**

when there is no sourceActivity(A) no base instance(A) left to invoke "onActivityResult" callback.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can simply override BaseActivity `onActivityResult` on fragment `baseActivity.startActivityForResult`.
2. On BaseActivity add interface

   `private OnBaseActivityResult baseActivityResult;`
3. On Fragment implements **OnBaseActivityResult**

[Check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29369154/1283715)

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom DialogFragment and I faced the same issue. No need to trigger it from the parent's method. You have to call startActivityForResult() and not getActivity().startActivityForResult() just like @umesh answered above.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `startActivityForResult` from a fragment, the result is sent back to your activity's `onActivityResult`. Instead use `super.onactivityResult` in your activity's `onActivityResult` and the result will instead be sent back to your fragment's `onActivityResult`. You can write your code here. Don't use `getActivity.onactivityResult` in your fragment's `onActivityResult`because it will refer to the activity's `onActivityResult`.